# MySQL multi table user_id does not exist query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables like such:

```
User table
user_id     first_name     email
1           Bob            bob@bob.com
2           Jane           jane@jane.com
3           Fred           fred@fred.com

Listing
listing_id  user_id        status
1           1              1
2           1              1
3           2              1
4           3              1

User billing
billing_id  user_id        status
1           1              1
2           2              1
```

The user table has all the user information.
The listing table has information about an auction listing. The status column of this table is to determine if the listing is active or ended.
The billing table has information related to the users billing details.

All tables are related based on user_id. What I would like to extract is all the user information where a user has an active listings but has not entered their billing details. So the desired result of the above tables example would be

```
user_id     first_name     email
3           Fred           fred@fred.com
```

as Fred currently has an active listings but has not filled out his billing information.

Many thanks.

Comment: I have tried some left joins and some IS NULL but neither produced the results I needed.

Comment: NOT IN will work but takes more time & resources to execute then a left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM User u
INNER JOIN Listing l USING (user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN User_billing b USING (user_id)
WHERE b.user_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This one seems to work thanks. I added in the WHERE l.status clause and worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Something like this.

```
select * from usertable inner join listing on usertable.user_Id=listing.user_Id
```

Using this you can get the data from this both table .
You got my point?

Comment: Hi this one isn't working. It is producing results even though users have inactive listings. It is showing users that haven't added billing details but not restricting it to active listings only.

Comment: You should add WHERE user.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM billing)

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
SELECT user.user_id, user.first_name, user.email 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN listing ON listing.user_id = user.user_id AND listing.status = 1
WHERE user.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM billing)
```

or...

```
SELECT user.user_id, user.first_name, user.email 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN listing ON listing.user_id = user.user_id AND listing.status = 1
LEFT JOIN billing ON billing.user_id = user.user_id
WHERE billing.user_id IS NULL
```

I recommend the second method over the first simply because of the NOT IN and the execution time vs a LEFT JOIN which is much faster and uses less resources